# Using the result of one query in dropping a constraint

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, alter

I have only one foreign key for my table `dependents` and I don't know the name of my foreign key, so I want to retrieve the name of key and drop it.

This is what i tried, but no use:

```
alter table dependents 
    drop constraint 
        select CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
        where TABLE_NAME = 'dependents' and constraint_name like 'FK%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not clear about **what** concrete RDBMS you're using - but in the case of SQL Server, you cannot do this `SELECT` inside the `ALTER TABLE` command - you have to do it **before** calling `ALTER TABLE`. And also: you cannot just simply call `ALTER TABLE` with a variable for the name of the constraint - you need to resort to using dynamic SQL - something like this:

```
DECLARE @FkConstraintName SYSNAME;

SELECT @FkConstraintName = CONSTRAINT_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'dependents'
  AND constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY';

DECLARE @DropStmt NVARCHAR(MAX)
    = N'ALTER TABLE dependents
        DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @FkConstraintName;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @DropStmt;
```

This is just yet another good reason **WHY** you should give all your constraint **specific names** when creating them!